# Cookies when tunneling wordpress through ngrok

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, ngrok

I have set up a wordpress multisite on a vagrant debian running PHP7. Ngrok is running on node and the frontend shows perfectly on my tunneling address.

When i try to log into wordpress backend "wp-admin" trough the tunneling address i get this error:

> wordpress error cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser

Tried with different browsers, does not seem that the browser is the issue. I also registered that cookies are registered on the tunneling domain.

Anyone experienced the same thing? Any possible issues im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) and mapped domain. Did the trick.